# Remove Object From ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have one `ArrayList` and one `TreeSet` that hold the same object type.

```
TreeSet<StatusChangeDB> listToChange;
List<StatusChangeDB> originalList;
```

`StatusChangeDB` looks like...

```
public class StatusChangeDB implements Comparable<StatusChangeDB> {


    private String sector;
    private String superlayer;
    private String loclayer;
    private String locwire;
    private String problem_type;
    public StatusChangeDB() {
    }
...
...
getters and setters
hashCode()
equals(Object)
compareTo(...)
}
```

When original list is generated, the Object, StatusChangeDB, has 4 of 5 of its primitives set, i.e. sector, superlayer, loclayer, locwire. The originalList is displayed in a JTable which implements AbstractTableModel.

At some point in the process, the user selects the rows from the displayed table and assigns the "problemType", which creates TreeSet listToChange.

Now I would like to remove the values selected from the JTable once the "problemType" is "set". 
To do this, I cannot use a straight

```
originaList.removeAll(listToChange)
```

Because the objects differ by "problemType".

I have tried this method in my TableModel

```
public void removeRow(TreeSet<StatusChangeDB> listToChange) {
    //this.wireList.removeAll(statusChangeDBs); Does not work 
    //because objects are different
    for (StatusChangeDB row : listToChange) {
        for (StatusChangeDB statusChangeDB : originalList) {

            if (statusChangeDB.getSector().equals(row.getSector())
                    && statusChangeDB.getSuperlayer().equals(row.getSuperlayer())
                    && statusChangeDB.getLoclayer().equals(row.getLoclayer())
                    && statusChangeDB.getLocwire().equals(row.getLocwire())) {
                System.out.println("####### EQUAL #######");

                System.out.println(ro.getSector() + "  " + ro.getSuperlayer() + "  " + ro.getLoclayer() + "  "
                        + ro.getLocwire());
                 this.originalList.remove(statusChangeDB);
            }
        }
    }
```

This method does the job of finding the values that equal to one another, however the line

```
         this.originalList.remove(statusChangeDB);
```

produces the error

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException   at
>   java.util.AbstractList.remove(AbstractList.java:161)  at
>   java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(AbstractList.java:374)  at
>   java.util.AbstractCollection.remove(AbstractCollection.java:293)  at
>   database.ui.TableModel.removeRow(TableModel.java:95)

I have read the SO forums on this, but I am not able to construct the ArrayList using Arrays.asList because the ArrayList is dymnamically added to.
How can I accomplish this task of removing the Object from the ArrayList?
Please no comments on using DefaultTableModel instead of AbstractTable Model. The "all knowing" leaders of the project have requested the AbstractTableModel.

The code that sets the originalList is as follows:

```
public void setWireSet(Dataset<StatusChangeDB> wireDF) {
    setWireList(wireDF.collectAsList());
    updateTable();
}

public void setWireList(List<StatusChangeDB> wireList) {
    this.originalList = wireList;
}
```

Both lists are filled and when dumped to screen have the appropriate values assigned.

The assignment of originalList is if TableModel as

```
private List<StatusChangeDB> originalList;
private String[] colNames = { "Sector", "SuperLayer", "Layer", "Wire" };

public TableModel() {
    this.originalList = new ArrayList<StatusChangeDB>();
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that assigns `this.originalList`?

Comment: made an edit to reflect the filling of originalList. However both lists are filled appropriately.

Comment: We still can't see the type of list. It's almost certainly not `java.util.ArrayList`.

Comment: It is of ArrayList as stated in the question     edited bottom of post to reflect how the construction of originaList is done

Comment: Obviously the implementation of the `List` does not support removing elements. So, you cannot use the `remove`.

Comment: It is not an List, it is an ArrayList, see edit at bottom.

Comment: Please show what does `System.out.println(originalList.getClass())` say right before the exception.

Comment: class java.util.Arrays$ArrayList

Comment: `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` is not `java.util.ArrayList`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147310/discussion-between-mkunkel-and-kan).

Comment: between constructor TableModel()  and setWireList(...) which execute first?

Comment: Constructor of TableModel is first as my Mainframe to a GUI calls it. Once data is processed, setWireList is invoked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting this error because you are calling

```
 this.originalList.remove(statusChangeDB);
```

inside a for-loop which will be using the iterator of that list.

Add the values you want removed to a temporary Arraylist then remove them once the loop completes execution.

Have something like

```
for (StatusChangeDB row : listToChange) {

 ArrayList<StatusChangeDB> tempList = new ArrayList();
    for (StatusChangeDB statusChangeDB : originalList) {

        if (statusChangeDB.getSector().equals(row.getSector())
                && statusChangeDB.getSuperlayer().equals(row.getSuperlayer())
                && statusChangeDB.getLoclayer().equals(row.getLoclayer())
                && statusChangeDB.getLocwire().equals(row.getLocwire())) {
            System.out.println("####### EQUAL #######");

            System.out.println(ro.getSector() + "  " + ro.getSuperlayer() + "  " + ro.getLoclayer() + "  "
                    + ro.getLocwire());

  tempList.add(statusChangeDB);

        }


    }

this.originalList.removeAll(tempList);

}
```

**Update**

Keeping the above implementation

```
public void setWireList(List<StatusChangeDB> wireList) {
this.originalList = wireList;
}
```

should be

```
 public void setWireList(List<StatusChangeDB> wireList) {
this.originalList.addAll(wireList);
 }
```

Assuming

```
public TableModel() {
this.originalList = new ArrayList<StatusChangeDB>();
```

}

is called before

```
public void setWireList(List<StatusChangeDB> wireList) {
this.originalList = wireList;
}
```

Comment: The temporary list is listToChange

Comment: this line ` this.originalList.remove(statusChangeDB);` can only work after you have exited the ` for (StatusChangeDB statusChangeDB : originalList)` loop.

Comment: I just implemented your idea that as you were updating and I still receive the same error.

Comment: Also, your code has misplacement of curly-brackets with respect to access of templist.

Comment: OK, well in my version I had templist outside both foreach loops. However, both methods, yours or mine (different in placement of templist) produce the same error that was being reported.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147311/discussion-between-tapsey-and-mkunkel).

Comment: The change to
 public void setWireList(List<StatusChangeDB> wireList) {

this.originalList.addAll(wireList);

 }
was the cure. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you are getting `UnsupportedOperationException` because your `List` implementation doesn't support removal. To avoid this, just create an ArrayList<>:

`List<StatusChangeDB> originalList  = new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList(sourceList) );`

Secondly, to remove objects by some set of fields (instead of defining this logic explicitly in your `removeRow` method), just override `equals` method in StatusChangeDB which will compare those fields:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    StatusChangeDB other = (StatusChangeDB) obj;
    return Objects.equals(sector, other.sector) && Objects.equals(superlayer, other.superlayer)
            && Objects.equals(loclayer, other.loclayer) && Objects.equals(locwire, other.locwire);
}
```

Comment: I cannot use the equals to compare because technically the are different object by the value of problemType, and I need this to be in equals for a later comparison with a MYSQL database.

Comment: Also the generation of originalList is within another Class that passes it to a service which TableModel has access to. If I try 
     public void setWireList(List<StatusChangeDB> wireList) {
  this.wireList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(wireList));
  // this.wireList = wireList;
 }   
 i get the error
    Cannot infer type arguments for ArrayList<>

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of array list. A regular one, and `Arrays` helper class's one, which is immodifiable.

During creation of yuor arraylist from array, instead of doing

```
this.originalList=Arrays.asList(pArray);
```

which uses the immodifiable fake ArrayList, do

```
this.originalList=new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(pArray));
```

make sure to redo imports, because you may have a namespace class for ArrayList

Comment: Unfortunately I need to initialize originalList in the TableModel constructor, and at time of construction the values of originalList are not known until user processed a few functions

Comment: then just use this.originalList = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: using this.originalList = new ArrayList<>(); produces same error.